# Query mix de produtos oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Fiz um indicador aqui na empresa onde listo informações do produto, quantidade vendida, valor médio, etc. Isso em um periodo de tempo.

Agora preciso da seguinte informação:

**Qual é o produto que mais vezes apareceu na mesma nota de venda para cada produto da lista.**

Por Exemplo, sempre que eu vendo uma câmera IP, eu vendo uma fonte e 2 conectores. Logo, na minha busca para a câmera, o produto que mais vende junto é o conector.

Sequer eu tenho ideia de como começar esta avaliação. Será que existe alguma função do Oracle que possa me auxiliar?

Answer (score 2):

**SIMPLIFICANDO**

```
NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
NUMERONOTA
CODCLIENTE
CODPRODUTO
```

**CAMERAS**

```
SELECT NUMERONOTA
FROM   NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
WHERE  CODPRODUTO = 'CAMERA IP'
```

**VENDIDOS JUNTO**

```
SELECT *
FROM   NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
WHERE  CODPRODUTO <> 'CAMERA IP'
AND    NUMERONOTA IN (SELECT NUMERONOTA
                      FROM   NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
                      WHERE  CODPRODUTO = 'CAMERA IP')
```

**MAIS VENDIDOS JUNTOS**

```
SELECT CODPRODUTO , COUNT(*) QTD
FROM   NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
WHERE  CODPRODUTO <> 'CAMERA IP'
AND    NUMERONOTA IN (SELECT NUMERONOTA
                      FROM   NOTA_FISCAL_ITEM
                      WHERE  CODPRODUTO = 'CAMERA IP')
GROUP BY CODPRODUTO
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Uma simplificação todavia , nenhuma otimização e o problema real é um pouco mais complexo.

Comment: Lembrei diito depois   http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/443571-consulta-para-retornar-produtos-similares/

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta é bem genérica, mas creio que com a query abaixo você pode adaptar para teu uso.

Basicamente, no meu caso, ela lista as cargas(cameras) e suas notas fiscais(fonte, conectores). Note o segundo select dentro do from.
 Adapte ela para seu uso:

```
--- lista as cargas criadas no periodo e suas notas fiscais vinculadas
select NAME        CARGA,
       STATUS_CODE STATUS,
       TRUNC(CREATION_DATE) DATA_CRIACAO,
       notas.NotaFiscal NOTASFISCAIS
 from wsh_trips ,
      (select distinct wt.name      viagem,
                       a.trx_number NotaFiscal
            from 
               ra_customer_trx_all           a,
               wsh_trips                     wt,
               WSH_NEW_DELIVERIES            WND,
               WSH_DELIVERY_LEGS             WDL,
               WSH_TRIP_STOPS                WTS
            where trunc(a.trx_date)     between '01-JUL-12' AND '31-AGO-12'
             AND WND.DELIVERY_ID             = TO_NUMBER(A.INTERFACE_HEADER_ATTRIBUTE3(+))
             AND WND.DELIVERY_ID             = WDL.DELIVERY_ID
             AND WDL.PICK_UP_STOP_ID         = WTS.STOP_ID
             AND WTS.TRIP_ID                 = WT.TRIP_ID
             and a.status_trx <> 'VD'
            order by 1,2) Notas

 where trunc(CREATION_DATE) between '01-JUL-12' AND '31-JUL-12'       
       and name = Notas.viagem(+)
```