# Achar o item mais vendido juntamente com determinado item

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pl-sql

Para explicar, prefiro um exemplo:

*Quero descobrir qual item é mais o mais vendido juntamente com o salgado de frango.*

Para isso, tentei a seguinte abordagem e falhei miseravelmente por falta de conhecimento técnico:

-Buscar todos cupons (vendas) que contenham o código do salgado de frango [OK]
-Pegar todos itens desses cupons [OK]
**-Somar a quantidade individual de cada item que é vendido. O valor mais alto é o resultado.**

Tentei usar SQL somente.
A estrutura relevante das tabelas é a seguinte:

Tabela **produto**
codbarra | descricao

Tabela **venda**
idvenda | dtvenda

Tabela **vdaitem**
idvdaitem | vdaitem | codbarra | qtde | dtvenda

Comment: Não tenho a certeza de que a estrutura de tabelas esteja correcta. Parece estar a faltar uma coluna na tabela vdaitem para ligar à tabela venda

Comment: @JeffersonLucas: Sua abordagem está correta e é possível ser implementada de forma modular em T-SQL, através do uso de CTE (common table expression).

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 4):

Vamos fazer por partes.

1. Encontrar todas as vendas que contenham o código do salgado de
   frango

```
SELECT v.idvenda,
       v.dtvenda
  FROM venda v
 INNER JOIN vdaitem vi
    ON vi.idenda = v.idvenda
 INNER JOIN produto p
    ON p.codbarra = vi.codbarra
 WHERE p.codbarra = 'CODIGO_BARRA_SALGADO_FRANGO'  -- Aqui substitui pelo valor correto
```

2. Usando a query anterior vamos seleccionar os restantes produtos para cada uma das vendas:

```
;WITH VendasContendoSalgadoFrango AS
(
    SELECT v.idvenda,
           v.dtvenda
      FROM venda v
     INNER JOIN vdaitem vi_frango
        ON vi_frango.idvenda = v.idvenda
     INNER JOIN produto p_frango
        ON p_frango.codbarra = vi.codbarra
     WHERE p_frango.codbarra = 'CODIGO_BARRA_SALGADO_FRANGO' 
), RestantesProdutos AS
(
    SELECT vFrango.idvenda, 
           vFrango.dtvenda,
           vi.codbarra,
           p.descricao,
           vi.qtde
      FROM VendasContendoSalgadoFrango vFrango
      --Ligar outra vez às tabelas vdaitem e produto, desta vez para obter os restantes produtos to cupon que contem o código do salgado de frango
     INNER JOIN vdaitem vi
        ON vi.idvenda = vFrango.idvenda
     INNER JOIN produto p
        ON p.codbarra = vi.codbarra
       AND p.codbarra <> 'CODIGO_BARRA_SALGADO_FRANGO' -- Nao queremos os detalhes do salgado de frango uma segunda vez 
)
SELECT TOP 10 codbarra,
       descricao,
       COUNT(DISTINCT idvenda),
       SUM(qtde)
  FROM RestantesProdutos
 GROUP BY codbarra, descricao
 ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Isto irá listar o TOP 10 de vendas, em termos de número de artigos vendidos. Pode comparar isto com o número total de vendas (cupons) para excluir os valores discrepantes (pequeno numero de vendas contendo elevado numero de artigos VS elevado numero de vendas contendo um pequeno numero de artigos)

Comment: só colocaria o top 10 e o group by na segunda query para evitar de selecionar todos os itens na tabela temporaria e depois filtrar. em uma base com muitas vendas isso será um problema de desempenho.

Answer (score 4):

Fiz algo semelhante a poucos dias, a fim de facilitar a vida do usuário mostrando em primeiro lugar, os itens mais vendidos ao cliente selecionado, em seguida os itens mais vendidos de forma geral. Acredito ser bem próximo da sua necessidade.

Para isso usei o union e coloquei uma coluna para ordenar, para sua situação a query ficaria assim:

```
with rankVendas as (
select 
    codbarra,
    descricao,
    null as qtdVendida,
    0 as ordem
from produto p 
where p.codbarra='CodBarraSalgadoFrango'

union

Select top 10
    codbarra,
    descricao,
    sum(vi.qtde) as qtdVendida,
1 as ordem
from produto p
left outer join vdaitem vi on vi.codbarra = p.codbarra
where p.codbarra != 'CodBarraSalgadoFrango'
group by codbarra, descricao, ordem)

Select 
    codbarra,
    descricao
from rankVendas
order by ordem, qtdVendida desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a função agregada `SUM` agrupando pelo produto apenas nos itens que tenham nota junto com a descrição "salgado de frango":

```
SELECT TOP(1) p.descricao,
              SUM(vi.qtde) AS quantidade_total
  FROM venda v
       INNER JOIN vdaitem vi ON vi.idvenda = v.idvenda
       INNER JOIN produto p ON p.codbarra = vi.codbarra
 WHERE p.descricao <> 'salgado de frango'
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM vdaitem vi2
                     INNER JOIN produto p2 ON p2.codbarra = vi.codbarra
               WHERE vi2.idvenda = v.idvenda
                 AND p2.descricao = 'salgado de frango')
 GROUP BY p.descricao
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

---

Explicação da `query`:

- Utilizamos o `JOIN` para realizar a junção das tabelas `venda`, `vdaitem` e `produto`. (Note que na sua descrição não existe coluna de vínculo entre a `vdaitem` e a `venda`, portanto eu levei em consideração que exista e que se chame `idvenda`);
- Realizamos a restrição no `WHERE` para impedir que o produto com a descrição "salgado de frango" seja considerada;
- Restringimos utilizando o `EXISTS` as vendas que possuem o item algum item com a descrição "salgado de frango" garantindo assim que estamos pegando todos os registros que **não são** "salgado de frango" mas possuem vínculo de itens junto ao mesmo;
- Agrupamos utilizando a cláusula `GROUP BY` pela coluna `descricao` da tabela `produto`;
- Utilizamos a função agregada `SUM` na quantidade dos itens resultantes;
- Ordenamos de forma decrescente (`DESC`) utilizando `ORDER BY` pela coluna de ordem 2, que neste caso é a somatória;
- Restringimos mais ainda o resultado utilizando a expressão `TOP` com a quantidade de registros desejados.

---

> [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189463(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Limita as linhas retornadas em um conjunto de resultados de consulta a um número ou percentual de linhas no SQL Server 2014. Quando TOP é usado junto com a cláusula ORDER BY, o conjunto de resultados é limitado ao primeiro número N de linhas ordenadas; caso contrário, ele retorna o primeiro número N de linhas em uma ordem indefinida. Use esta cláusula para especificar o número de linhas retornado de uma instrução SELECT ou afetado por uma instrução INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE ou DELETE.

---

> [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187810(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna a soma de todos os valores ou somente os valores DISTINCT na expressão. SUM pode ser usado exclusivamente com colunas numéricas. Valores nulos são ignorados.

---

> [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188336(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Especifica uma subconsulta a ser testada quanto à existência de linhas.

---

> [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Agrupa um conjunto de linhas selecionadas em um conjunto de linhas de resumo pelos valores de uma ou mais colunas ou expressões no SQL Server. Uma linha é retornada para cada grupo. As funções de agregação na lista de  da cláusula SELECT fornecem informações sobre cada grupo em vez de linhas individuais.

---

> [`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188385(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Classifica os dados retornados por uma consulta no SQL Server.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129467/query-mix-de-produtos-oracle

Comment: @Motta praticamente a mesma coisa, dei até um upvote lá. Não sabia que o número da coluna no order funcionava no Oracle também

Comment: Problema recorrente , software como SAS fazem isto melhor mas muitas vezes a solução tem de vir de SQL mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

> *Quero descobrir qual item é mais o mais vendido juntamente com o salgado de frango.*

A solução proposta nesta resposta segue a lógica definida pelo autor, utilizando [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972.aspx) (common table expressions) para implementá-la. Considera ainda que existe coluna `idvenda` na tabela `vdaitem`, de modo a permitir o relacionamento entre a venda e os itens vendidos.

Eis sugestão para obter o que é solicitado:

```
-- código #1
declare @CodFrango int;
set @CodFrango= informe o codigo de barra do salgado de frango;

with 
VendasComFrango as (
SELECT distinct idvenda
  from vdaitem
  where codbarra = @codFrango
),
VendasPorProduto as (
SELECT VI.codbarra, sum(VI.qtde) as SomaQtde
  from vdaitem as VI
       inner join VendasComFrango as VCF on VCF.idvenda = VI.idvenda
  where VI.codbarra <> @codFrango
  group by VI.codbarra
)
SELECT top (1) VPP.codbarra, 
       (SELECT descricao from produto as P where P.codbarra = VPP.codbarra) as Produto,
       somaQtde
  from VendasPorProduto as VPP
  order by VPP.SomaQtde desc;
```

O código é *enxuto*, utilizando o mínimo de recursos (memória, principalmente). Por exemplo, a tabela de produtos somente é associada ao final, para obter a descrição do produto.

A variável `@CodFrango` deve ser declarada da mesma forma que a coluna `codbarra` da tabela `produto`.