# Encontrar um item mais vendido juntamente com outro

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Encontrar um item mais vendido juntamente com outro. Sql server

TABELA VENDA CAMPOS =  ttcupomfiscalitem

[image: Cupomfiscal]

TABELA PRODUTO CAMPOS = ( tcprodutos)

[image: Produtos]

**Tentei fazer a seguinte consulta sqlserver**

```
SELECT TOP (10) c.chavecontrole   AS cupom, 
                p.descricao, 
                c.produto, 
                Sum(c.quantidade) AS quantidade 
FROM   tcprodutos p 
       INNER JOIN ttcupomfiscalitem c 
               ON p.produto = c.produto 
                  AND c.produto = '222110165' 
GROUP  BY c.chavecontrole, 
          p.descricao, 
          c.produto 
ORDER  BY quantidade DESC;
```

***Resultado =***

[image: RESULTADO DA CONSULTA]

Os resultados aparecem o mesmo produto, como fazer para aparecer os outro itens do mesmo cumpom por quantidade?

Comment: vc tá filtrando pra só um produto... `c.produto = '222110165'`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, No entanto queria saber qual produto vende mais junto com '222110165', 
Como faço para aparecer os outros itens do cupom que tenha o produto = 222110165 no mesmo cupom. Não sei se ficou claro. Não sei como fazer esse filtro.

Comment: Selecione os distintos "cupom" que tem o produto x , faça um select destes "cupom" ( in , exists etc) contando os produtos que não sejam o produto x. Conte os maiores . Devem existir umas 564 outras soluções possíveis deste problema recorrente.    https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226495/achar-o-item-mais-vendido-juntamente-com-determinado-item

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Achar o item mais vendido juntamente com determinado item](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226495/achar-o-item-mais-vendido-juntamente-com-determinado-item)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP(1) p.descricao,
              SUM(i.quantidade) AS quantidade_total
  FROM ttcupomfiscalitem i
       INNER JOIN tcprodutos p ON p.produto = i.produto
 WHERE i.produto <> '222110165'
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM ttcupomfiscalitem i2
               WHERE i2.cupom = i.cupom
                 AND i2.produto = '222110165')
 GROUP BY p.descricao
 ORDER BY 2
```

Referência: [**Achar o item mais vendido juntamente com determinado item**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226513/59479)